# PartialLink text for selecting value in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: Search google with word 'Selenium' and click on the first link.

I have written this below code:

```
`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.com/");


driver.manage().window().maximize();



driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");

List<WebElement> alist = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Selenium"));

System.out.println(alist.size());`
```

but it is giving me size as zero. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you are going to find list of all links with partial text `Selenium`, all links are not present in the `DOM` due to fast execution. You should try using `WebDriver` to wait until all elements visible in the `DOM` as below :-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

List<WebElement> alist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.partialLinkText("Selenium")))

System.out.println(alist.size());
```

**Output**:-13

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 1):

ur problem occurs because u don't wait after searching. just wait a little moment so that browser can search and show the result. use the below code :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Selenium");
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

though this kind of wait is not recommended to use. Try to use wait by using until like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("element css path")));
```

u can use by xpath or id or class here.